# What is the exact behaviour of MPI_Wait following an MPI_Isend?

Tags: c++, c, mpi, nonblocking

I have read all the MPI documentation and tutorials and Stack Overflow questions that I could find relevant to this, but I still do not fully understand how MPI_Wait behaves when "completing" an MPI_Isend. Can we summarize it succinctly? Does it

- A. Return when the buffer used in the corresponding Isend is usable
  again (I think yes, but this doesn't tell me everything I want to
  know).
- B. Return when the corresponding Recv completes (I think not
  necessarily, but maybe sometimes if the message is large?)
- C. Guarantee that the Recv can be completed by the receiving process at some later time after it returns

I ask because I am trying to implement a kind of non-blocking broadcast (since MPI_Ibcast is an MPI 3 thing and doesn't seem to exist in any of the implementations I actually encounter). The sequence I am currently following on each process is this:

1. `MPI_Isend` from every process to every other process
2. Do some other work
3. `MPI_Wait` for all the Isends to 'complete', whatever that means exactly
4. `MPI_Recv` all the messages

This seems to work fine in practice, but I don't know if it is *guaranteed* to work, or if I am just lucky because my messages are small (they are just one int each, so I suspect that they get rapidly shuffled off by MPI into some internal buffers or whatever). I don't know whether this would create deadlocks if the messages were bigger (I worry that in this case not all the MPI_Waits would return, because some might be deadlocked waiting for MPI_Recvs to happen on another process).

If this is not guaranteed to work in general, is it at least guaranteed to work for very small messages? Or is even this not necessarily true? I am really not sure what I can count on here.

If this is not guaranteed to work then how can a non-blocking broadcast be implemented? Perhaps there is some clever sequence of performing the Waits and Recvs that works out? Like first rank 0 Waits for rank 1 to Recv, then rank 1 Waits for rank 0 to Recv? Is some kind of switched pairing arrangement like that more correct?

Comment: A and only A. If messages are short enough, they might be sent in eager mode, if your MPI library implements a progress thread, they might be sent immediately too. The standard does not mandate any of these, so your only safe assumption is `MPI_Wait()` will return after a matching receive is posted.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Well I guess I will try to figure out how to order everything so that happens then... it should be possible somehow I guess...

Comment: Btw, both Open MPI and MPICH implements `MPI_Ibcast()`

Comment: Ok so next question: I assume that the Recv's can complete without the Wait being posted? Does that mean I can just swap (4) and (3) in my ordering and it should be fine?

Comment: You **have to** swap 4 and 3 in order to prevent deadlocks.

Comment: Right, cool, but so long as that is sufficient :). I was just concerned that the Recv's might not complete until the corresponding Wait was posted, so that swapping the order might still result in deadlocks. But if that is not the case then I am very happy to hear it!

Comment: Since you are in the C++ real I recommend to ditch raw MPI usage and use boost::mpi. I tried raw MPI first, and had so much hassle I was spared after switching to the boost abstraction, see https://github.com/Superlokkus/dist_vec_ret for both.

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions are met by the following:

`MPI_Isend` followed by `MPI_Wait` both complete:

> A. The buffer used in the corresponding `Isend` is usable again.

If you were to use `MPI_Issend` and `MPI_Wait`:

> **almost** B. Return when the corresponding Recv **is posted**.

The following is true right after `MPI_Send`:

> C. Guarantee that **a matching** Recv can be completed by the receiving process at some later time after it returns.

In your suggested non-blocking broadcast, you would have to **allow** to swap 3. and 4., otherwise there is a deadlock. That means, there must not be a strict condition that 4. happens after 3. Since 3 happens on the root, and 4 happens on all other ranks, it may not even be an issue.

I would, however suggest to instead a cleaner approach:

1. `MPI_Isend` on the root to **all** processes
2. `MPI_Irecv` on **all88 processes from the root
3. Do some other work (on all processes)
4. `MPI_Waitall` for all posted requests (both `send`/`recv`) on all ranks

That should be clean to implement and work just fine. Of course that is not an optimized collective... but that is another topic.